# Certificado SSL en backend y frontend wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, certificado-ssl

Tengo una web que en el frontend aparece el candado verde del certificado SSL, pero al acceder al backend de wordpress no aparece. De primeras, no sé si es una tontería.

Al mismo tiempo algunos usuarios han experimentado que da problema de seguridad cuando acceden desde móviles android, no iOS. Les aparece el cartel que puede ser una página no segura.

Tengo otras páginas con Wordpress y el certificado SSL y funcionan perfectamente. No sé que puede ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asunto resuelto.
Era problema del contenido mixto en backend. 
Regeneré el certificado y con el inspector de elementos de chrome en el backend busqué en "Console" y "Security" el error. El error era una url de una imagen que apuntaba a "http" en lugar de "https". Borré la imagen y la volví a subir al servidor y todo funciona correctamente.
Ya tengo el candado verde en front y backend.

Answer (score 1):

Si en tu instalación original de wordpress configuraste la url con http en vez de https, los links internos seguirán siendo http. Podrías intentar hacer ese cambio en el panel, si corresponde.

Puntualmente, para forzar que el login y el panel de administración se accedan con https, puedes editar tu `wp-config.php` y poner

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true );
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
```

¿Qué tipo de certificado estás usando? ¿Compraste uno, generaste uno gratis con let's encrypt, estás usando universal SSL de Cloudflare? Dependiendo de cómo lo has implementado, puede que la cadena de certificados que está configurada en el vhost (de apache o nginx) no esté en el orden correcto. En escritorio e ios esto es ignorado, pero Android es más estricto.

Pega tu dominio en https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html y revisa s i hay advertencias.

Comment: Me sale "B" en el test. Desde el servidor me han dicho que regenere el certificado. Lo hice con let's encrypt, y tengo otras webs igual, que funcionan bien. ¿Debo utilizar plugins como Really Simple SSL para esta tarea? o prescindo de ello.